# how to apply window with KStreams {use case with java}

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
KStream<String, dummy> demoZone = builder.stream(fromTopic, Consumed.with(Serializer.getSerde(String.class), Serializer.getSerde(dummy.class)));
```

I want to apply window on demoZone of 1 minutes and find average of that 1 min data

Comment: KStream<String, dummy> demoZone = builder.stream(fromTopic, Consumed.with(Serializer.getSerde(String.class), Serializer.getSerde(dummy.class)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimeWindow as given below :

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> averageCount = demoZone
        .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), dummySerde()))
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5).advanceBy(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))))
        .reduce(// Your aggregate logic here);
```

You can find more details about Windowing here :
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing